# How to evaluate this limit of a finite sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, lebesgue-measure, divergent-series

I am trying to evaluate the following limit:

$$lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n} {\frac{1}{(n+k)^\frac{1}{ n}}}$$

At first I thought that, since this is an infinite limit of a finite sum (partial sums), it would just be the infinite series of the inner term - and so I would need to do the convergence tests - but I'm not sure.

I also thought of exchanging the limit with the sum (evaluate the limit of the term inside the sum first and then sum it) - but I know it has to do with measure theory (Dominated Convergence Theorem), but I don't know so much about that theory.

If you have any ideas on what's the right way to approach this, please help.

Comment: $n^{1/n} < (n+k)^{1/n} \leqslant (2n)^{1/n}$ for $1 \leqslant k \leqslant n$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Got it! It goes to infinity. Maybe I'll try writing my own answer sometime later. Thanks!